# Is it possible to create a consumable subscription for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

We already have a monthly payment option. But client wants to have a 2 year and lifetime pay up front payment option. For lifetime option it's probably fine, but the maximum period for subscription is 1 year, there is no 2 year option. To avoid payment failure after 1 year, our client wants the payment for 2 year to be done upfront. Is it allowed by Apple/Google to have a consumable which when "consumed" it will be swapped with a 2 year subscription?

Related posts for Apple, but there is no confirmation if this is possible

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/101513
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127072

Comment: If you use a non-auto renewing subscription then you have full control over the subscription period, but the user will need to re-subscribe manually at the end of the two year period.